# Why my while loop in not getting repeated in this switch case?

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    int if_again = 1;
    int c = 1;
    switch (a)
    {
    case 1:
        while (if_again == 1)
        {
            scanf("%d", c);
            if (c == 1)
            {
                if_again == 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if_again == 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is getting terminated after giving 1 two times only, but it should keep on getting repeated until 0 is entered. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `scanf("%d", c);` -> `scanf("%d", &c);` You should have got some warnings from the compiler.

Comment: `if_again == 1;` does nothing. You probably want `if_again = 1;` Didn't you get compiler warnings? If not compile allways with `-Wall`

Comment: And you would have seen that if you had enabled appropriate compiler warnings: `warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]` Those are to help you.

Comment: OT: this code looks overly complicated. You don't need the switch/case at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scanf needs the base address of a variable you give it. So `scanf("%d, c);` needs to be `scanf(%d, &c);`

The following code is also wrong:

```
if (c == 1)
{
   if_again == 1;
}
```

The compiler thinks that you are comparing "if_again" with 1. I think you are trying to set the variable to 1? In that case do this:

```
if (c == 1)
{
   if_again = 1;
}
```

The same is true for the `else` statement.

Also, why is there a switch statement? If you want to see it `a` is 1, then just to an `if`

Comment: I was using it in a question, The code I gave was just the part of it .Thanks